# Image pixels in iPhone simulator vs iPhone device

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, resolution, image-resizing

I'm displaying a 68x68 pixel image into my iPhone app. That's the resolution of a profile thumbnail in Facebook's iphone app. In my iPHone simulator, however, it looks much larger than a thumbnail. Is this because my computer's resolution is much lower than my iPhone's? Will the images be smaller if i run the same app on hardware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check the size of the imageview that is showing the image and the UIViewContentMode..

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer **YES**. And please check your `UIImageView` is 68x68.

Comment: I'm using HJCache (http://www.markj.net/hjcache-iphone-image-cache/) so I create an HJManagedImageV object, and it is set to 68x68. So I expect they will be much smaller on the device. Thank you.